# how to plot 200 periods and each period have list of 200 values in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame which has 200 columns and each column is a list of 200 values.

I want to plot those values in series in such a way that

- First column (100 values) lie between 0 to 1 in x-axis
- Second column (200 values) lie between 1 to 2 in x-axis
- Third column (200 values) lie between 2 to 3 in x-axis
- ...

is there any way in python to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean first column (200 values)? And what do you mean by lie between 0 to 1? Do you want to introduce jitter to the points? Also, please show what you have already done and where exactly you need help

Comment: first column(200 values) mean
df["first_column] = [1,2,3,4,5.......200]
df["second_column] = [5,6,24,654,36,.......200]
so on
and no i dont want to add jitters.

lie between 0 to 1 means :

Comment: lie between 0 to 1 means : value i want to plot for df["first_column"] should be plot between 0 to 1
and df["second_column"] should plot between 1 to 2

Answer (score 0):

So, I gather that by "between 0 and 1", you actually want the points of Column 1 situated at x=0.5. To have all values of Column 1 at the same x-coordinate, just pass that fixed x-coordinate to the call to `scatter`. I show here the example for 20 columns with 20 values per column:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(20):
    df[f'Col {i}'] = np.random.randn(20)

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
for i in range(20):
    axes.scatter([i+0.5]*len(df), df[f'Col {i}'])
axes.set_xticks(range(20))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to iterate over the columns (or column keys) because one is flexible with the column names. This code snippet is a quick example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# create random data with non-serial column names
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=['Col 1','Col 2','Col 4','Col 5'])

fig, ax= plt.subplots()

# creating a list of DataFramecolumns 
columns = list(df) 
# iterate over columns of the DataFrame
for i,col in enumerate(columns):
    y = df[col]
    x = [i+0.5] * len(y)
    ax.scatter(x,y)

plt.show()
```

[image: output]